# Reading .XLS Files into R

Tags: r, excel, xlsx, xls

I have a particular file that is a .xls file extension and am having trouble reading it into R. I have tried a number of different solutions, all of which have been failing.

1. `read_xls()`

```
var1 <- read_xls("dest.xls", sheet = "sheetname")
```

> libxls error: Unable to open file

2. `read.xlsx()`

```
var1 <- read.xlsx("dest.xls", sheetName = "sheetname", startRow = 5))
```

> Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod",
>   cl,  :    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Your InputStream was
>   neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream

3. `read_excel()`

```
var1<-read_excel("dest.xls", sheet = 1, col_names = TRUE, col_types = NULL, na ="", skip = 0)
```

> libxls error: Unable to open file

4. `loadWorkbook()`

```
file <- list.files("dest", pattern = 'xls', full.names = T)

wb <- loadWorkbook(file)
```

> Error: IllegalArgumentException (Java): Your InputStream was neither
>   an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream

5. `odbcConnectExcel()`

```
conn <- odbcConnectExcel("dest.xls")
```

> odbcConnectExcel is only usable with 32-bit Windows

Not really sure what the issue is. Oddly enough when I open the file into excel I receive the following error - which also may be a contributor.

> "The file format and extension of "file.xls" don't match. The file
>   could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open
>   it. Do you want to open it anyway? - Yes

Upon clicking yes I have access to the data.

Very strange any help would be awesome - thanks guys!

Comment: What happens if you re-save it from excel as "dest2.xls" and open that in R?

Comment: If I open the spreadsheet and save it manually as .XLS or as .XLSX it then is able to be read in R. Is there anyway in R to manually convert and resave the file?

Comment: That means that although it is labelled as.xls, it must be in a different format, but one still readable by Excel. If you knew what that file type was you could just rename it with the correct extension in R and load it in as appropriate. The most likely candidates are `.xlsx`, and `.csv`

Comment: How would you recommend finding the true file format? I am scraping the file from a website and when I download it naturally from google chrome it shows up as 

Type of file : Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet (.xls)

Comment: Are you using `download.file`? If so, try using it with `method = "wb"`

Comment: Correct, that is what I am using.

Comment: Can you open the file if you save it as `download.file(url, path, method = "wb")`?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is how I have been downloading the file, if I alternate between .XLS or XLSX on its extension I still receive the same error when opening in Excel and can't read it into R. 

Its weird because if I open it in excel and just resave it and overwrite the original- R can read it - both .XLS and .XLSX

Comment: Maybe add the link if that's possible?

Comment: I believe the issue is lying within Excel not trusting the document. Are you aware of anyway in Excel to allow documents to be trusted. 

I think we want to remove the "The file format and extension of "file.xls" don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?" error.

When we open it and resave it, it then becomes trusted I believe, not blocking R from reading it

Comment: Also when I go to resave it, Excel is defaulting to filename.xls with the file format .XML

Comment: You could try saving it as a.xml and reading it with the xml2 library. Just `install.packages("xml2")` and `read_xml('yourfile.xls")`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert an XLS file to XLSX with the following function using the RDCOMClient package :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
convert_XLS_File_To_XLSX <- function(path_XLS_File, path_XLSX_File)
{
  xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
  xlApp[['Visible']] <- FALSE
  xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_XLS_File)
  xlWbk$SaveAs(path_XLSX_File, 51)
  xlWbk$Close()
  xlApp$Quit()
}
```

Then, you can read the xlsx file with, for example, the R package openxlsx.